# Use Linq to query JSon objects and compare the same

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, json, linq

I want to form a linq query to find the cheapest price of a book

I have tried the following

```
Books[] books = new Books[]
    {
        new Books { ID = 1001, Name = "The Alchemist"},
        new Books { ID = 1002, Name = "The Zahir"},
        new Books { ID = 1003, Name = "Monk who sold his Ferrari"}
    };

BookStore1[] bookstore1 = new BookStore1[]
    {
        new BookStore1  { ID = 1001 , Price = 1,Source = "BookStore1" },
        new BookStore1  { ID = 1002 ,Price = 200, Source = "BookStore1"  },
        new BookStore1  { ID = 1003 ,Price = 150, Source = "BookStore1"  }
    };

    BookStore2[] bookstore2 = new BookStore2[]
    {
        new BookStore2  { ID = 1001 , Price = 2,Source = "BookStore2" },
        new BookStore2  { ID = 1002 ,Price = 100, Source = "BookStore2"  },
        new BookStore2  { ID = 1003 ,Price = 130, Source = "BookStore2"  }
    };
```

I have a search box

```
<div>
Search:
<input id="txtQuery" type="text" />
<input id="btnSearch" type="button" value="Search" />
</div>
```

When I enter The Alchemist in the search, onclick event is triggered. I have the following javascript for the event call

```
$('#btnSearch').click(function () {
    var bookname = $('#txtQuery').val();
    if (bookname == "") { // if search is blank it returns list of all the books.
        $.get('/api/AllBooks?token=' + SecurityManager.generate(), function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (key, item) {
                // Add a list item for the product.
                $('<p>', { text: formatItem(item) }).appendTo($('#result'));
            });
        });
    }
    else { // search based on ID
        $.get('/api/find?q=' + bookname + '&token=' + SecurityManager.generate(), function (data) {

            if (data.length > 1) {
                $.each(data, function (key, item) {
                    // Add a list item for the product.
                      $('<p>', { text: formatItem(item) }).appendTo($('#result'));
                });
            }
            else { $('#result').text(formatItem(data)); }
        });
    }

 function formatItem(item) {
    return item.ID + ':Movie' + item.Name
}
```

I have a function in my APIcontroller called Find
**The catch is I want the user to enter the Name of the book in the search, however when the Api is called in the click event it should pass the ID of the bookname
eg: The alchemist is entered in the search box. On button click
'/api/find?q=' + bookname + ' -> here the bookname should be 1001
How do i achieve this?**

The second catch is in the find function below

```
public JsonResult find(int q)
    {
//**some code here to find from bookstore1 and bookstore2 the cheapest price for ID 1001 based on the value entered in the searchbox.**
//var book = books.FirstOrDefault((p) => p.Id == id);
// var movie = bookstore1.Concat(bookstore2); cannot be done as both the datatypes are different
//var books = books.Where(p => p.Name.ToLower().Contains(q)).OrderBy(p=>p.Price).FirstOrDefault();
// return Json(books, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

I have commented the code that i have tried but did not find success. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: i think you shouldnt create 2 bookstrore objects (bookstore1 and 2). just create 1 bookstore. Inside this bookstore is both of bookstore1 and 2

Comment: @Mark did u mean something like this     BookStore[] bookstore = new BookStore[]
    {
        new BookStore  { ID = 1001 , Price = 1,Source = "BookStore1" },
        new BookStore  { ID = 1002 ,Price = 200, Source = "BookStore1"  },
        new BookStore  { ID = 1003 ,Price = 150, Source = "BookStore1"  }
        new BookStore  { ID = 1001 , Price = 2,Source = "BookStore2" },
        new BookStore  { ID = 1002 ,Price = 100, Source = "BookStore2"  },
        new BookStore  { ID = 1003 ,Price = 130, Source = "BookStore2"  }
    };

Comment: yap, that exactly what i mean. you should do it like that. then it would be easier for u to find the minimum price

Comment: @Mark Thanks mate. I got that working but I am facing a problem in the ID part. as mentioned in my q above I have a function in my API controller called Find The catch is I want the user to enter the Name of the book in the search box, however when the Api is called in the click event it should pass the ID of the bookname eg: The alchemist is entered in the search box. On button click '/api/find?q=' + bookname + ' -> here the bookname should be 1001 How do i achieve this? rite now i tried with 1001 and ur soln worked. please guide me on this catch as well.

Comment: I think that would be a bad design, but the only work around that I can think is to create a function that accept Bookname, and return its ID. after you got the ID, then you send it to the API. that would be much more efficient, if the API could be changed. API input should be the same with WEB input

Comment: @Mark I get what u say. I have an exercise to build an app which would compare books from 2 databases and return the book with the cheapest price among the databases. I have 2 apis one which will return all books /api/{bookstore1 or bookstore2}/books and the other wil return a single book based on the ID fetch api/{bookstore1 or bookstore2}/books/{ID}. am i doing the right way? will i achieve it with the way you have suggested. Thanks mate appreciate your time and effort.

Comment: is that mean, that you create the API by yourself? then you should change the input of your API. should be `api/{bookstore1 or bookstore2}/books/{bookname}`. Then your API will search in the database, the bookname that has the cheapest price. this way, you dont need to convert BOOKNAME into ID

Comment: @Mark no the API for ID is already created which is why I want to search on ID. Does that mean I should type the ID on the search box instead of the book name?